# How use boundaries of time with spring roo?

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-roo

This is a project example.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23715281/TestRoo.zip

And this is a details of project.

```
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Employee --testAutomatically 
field string --fieldName name --notNull
field string --fieldName workposition --notNull 
field number --fieldName salary --type java.lang.Double
```

Between month value of salary maybe changes (Increase or Decreace).  My question is how to adapt this project if i want to reset a salary when month end. you can show me a demonstration for use boundaries of time in roo project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a custom service which gets invoked using a scheduler and performs this function on your entities.

Comment: you can show me a line of roo command that you use for performs schedule

Comment: You should do it the way you normally do with Spring framework and it would work just fine with Roo. :)

Comment: I'm newbie in roo you can guide me. How to customize it and which file you edit. Thanks in advanced